# Auto Generate fields of form in php

Tags: php, forms

I have a form something like,

```
<form>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
Date <input type="text" name="date" id="date">
</td>
<td>
Installment <input type="text" name="installment" id="installment">
</td>
<td>
Balance <input type="text" name="balance" id="balance">
</td>
</tr>
</form>
```

The Thing I want is that to auto generate these fields of form when the value of the field name="balance" exceeds zero.

if you guys have any idea. Please answer me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you supply the PHP code you have used?

Comment: @Termis: I use nothing, because I don't know how to do that in php. have you any idea for this?

Comment: What do you mean by auto generating? Do you want to generate the values or the fields itself?

Comment: You want to generate the `date` and `installment` in the client side .. right?

Comment: I want to auto generate all the fields in client side when the balance exceeds 0.

Comment: Is this possible in javascript or in php? If possible than please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options for implementing this.
You can create the fields in the server-side but set its `display:none`. When the value of the balance test field is greater than `0` set the `display:none`
Or you can create the fields from the JavaScript itself

I have written a sample code(assuming you are using jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#balance').change(function() {
      if($(this).val() > 0)
      {
        $('<input>').attr({
                        type: 'text',
                        name: 'date',
                        id: 'date'
                    }).appendTo($("#formId"));
        $('<input>').attr({
                        type: 'text',
                        name: 'installment',
                        id: 'installment'
                    }).appendTo($("#formId"));
      }
      else
      {
        $('#date').remove();
        $('#installment').remove();
      }
    });

    $('#removeRow').click(function() {
        $('#date').remove();
        $('#installment').remove();
    });

});
```

[EDIT] : included the code to remove the row

Comment: thanks buddy, it works. But still there is a problem. there is no option to remove the row or to go back.

Comment: is there any way to remove these fields in javascript?

Comment: I have updated the code. Create any element with id `removeRow`

Comment: Suppose, I entered the numeric value in balance field greater than zero and fields are generated automatically. Then I decided to change the numeric value in balance field to 0, But what I saw, that fields are still there. I want to remove these fields automatically when balance again becomes 0.

Comment: you can accomplish it by simply putting an `else` condition. I have updated the code.

Comment: but i want to generate balance field again and when value of generated balance field exceeds 0 then these fields generate again.

Comment: What the above code does is `Whenever there is a change in the balance it will check if the balance is greater than zero. If balance is greater than zero then two textboxes will be created, and if the balance is less than or equal to zero the textboxes will be removed`. Isn't that you needed. I haven't tested that code is there any issues in it?